# Left and Right Grids to maintain widths according to a ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I am trying to create a window that contains both a left `Grid` and a right `Grid` (a sidebar). Initially the left `Grid` should fill the entire screen. However when an `image` in the left `Grid` is clicked, I want the width of the two `Grids` to adhere to some kind of ratio (eg: 70:30).

Also, even if the user clicks on the `Window` maximize button, I would like the `Grids` to maintain their proportions (70:30 if an `image` has been clicked or 100:0 otherwise).

I currently have the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="movieDisplay" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="1163"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedMovie.isMovieSelected}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="913" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="1163" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding _movies}"  SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_Home"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="sidebar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                <TextBlock Width="200" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                            <Binding Path = "SelectedMovie.title"/>
                            <Binding Path = "SelectedMovie.year"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="star_icon.png" Width="100"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedMovie.rating}" Style="{StaticResource AnnotationStyle}" Width="150"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I was informed that I shouldn't manually set the `Width` and `Height` properties if I want the `Grids` to maintain their ratios even when maximized. In some places I have left values for the `width` because I'm not sure what to set them to.

I'm also not sure how I can change the `Storyboard` `setter` to a ratio for the `width`.

[image]

This is what the panel should look like if a `Button` on the left has been clicked regardless of whether the `Panel` has been minimized or maximized.

When a button has not been clicked, the `Left Grid` should extend all the way to the right and fill the entire `Panel`.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I've put my content in a `ViewBox` and set the `Viewbox.Stretch Property` to `Stretch.Uniform` which seems to solve the issue of maintaining scale when the `Window` is maximized.

Still haven't worked out the ratio issue yet..

Comment: There is a special control for splitting grids called GridSplitter. GridSplitter Tutorial - http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/gridsplitter/.

Comment: @JesseJames Thanks for the suggestion however I don't want the user to alter the `Grid` sizes. When a `Button` is clicked, I need the `Grids` to adjust themselves automatically.

Comment: Search for `BoolToGridWidthConverter` and bind second column's visibility property to ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind column definitions' width:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <my:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding LeftGridWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RightGridWidth}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" Grid.Column="0">
        <Image Source="Resources/DemoImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowRightGridCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="RightGrid" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button>Something 1</Button>
            <Button>Something 2</Button>
            <Button>Something 3</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and have something like this in code, where your DataContext comes (like ViewModel):

```
    private GridLength _leftGridWidth;
    private GridLength _rightGridWidth;
    private readonly GridLength _defaultRightGridWidth = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ShowRightGridCommand = new DelegateCommand(SwitchRightGridWidth);
        LeftGridWidth = new GridLength(7, GridUnitType.Star);
        RightGridWidth = _defaultRightGridWidth;
    }

    private void SwitchRightGridWidth()
    {
        RightGridWidth = RightGridWidth == _defaultRightGridWidth ? new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) : _defaultRightGridWidth;
    }

    public GridLength LeftGridWidth
    {
        get { return _leftGridWidth; }
        set { _leftGridWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }


    public GridLength RightGridWidth
    {
        get { return _rightGridWidth; }
        set { _rightGridWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public ICommand ShowRightGridCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Janez. I'm in the process of trying this. Will get back to you :)